# Feynman propagator for spacelike points

Tags: quantum-field-theory, causality, propagator, klein-gordon-equation

When I calculate the feynman propagator for spacelike points for free scalar quantum field it is not zero. How do I interpret this result. Since it seems to me that it violates causality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right, for a free theory with scalar field $\phi$, the propagator $D(x-y)$ is non-zero for $(x-y)^2<0$. However, crucially the commutator $[\phi(x),\phi(y)]=D(x-y)-D(y-x)=0$. Basically, if a particle can travel from $x$ to $y$, the amplitude for the particle travelling from $y$ to $x$ cancels it out, saving the causality of the theory.

Comment: But in peskin and Schroeder this commutator $[\phi(x),\phi(y)]$ is not zero

Comment: http://home.ustc.edu.cn/~gengb/200923/Peskin,%20An%20Introduction%20to%20Quantum%20Field%20Theory.pdf Page 28 of this version of Peskin and Schroeder proves that this commutator vanishes for spacelike $x,y$.

Comment: Can there be any interpretation in terms of virtual particles?

Comment: Yes: the amplitude for the particle to travel from $x$ to $y$ cancels the amplitude for the antiparticle to travel from $y$ to $x$. In the case of a scalar field, the particle is its own antiparticle.

Comment: Can you please further clarify?

Comment: It would be helpful if you asked a specific question or highlighted what you want to understand.